# How do I remove a style element from an inline style using regex?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, regex

I am trying to remove only one property i.e `float` and its value, from an inline style. I would like to start with this:

```
<div id="first_line_info" style="width:490px; float:right;"> </div>
```

And make it like this:

```
<div id="first_line_info" style="width:490px"> </div>
```

So far I have tried this code:

```
Regex noInlineStylePattern = new Regex("style=\"[^\"]*\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
data = noInlineStylePattern.Replace(data, "");
```

This removes all of the inline styles. How can I just remove the float?

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Only instances of `float:right;`? Any `float` style? All styles except `width`?

Comment: I would like to remove all the floats and leave the width. There are more than one float in the documents HTML that I am using.

Comment: In addition, you might want to take a look at [Should hi, thanks, taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: why not remove all inline styles and replace them with classes in the CSS?

Comment: at first I wondered why the question had so many downvotes, then I looked at the history

Answer (score 16):

This should remove all floats:

```
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"(style=\"".*?)(float:\s*[^;\""]+;?)(.*?\"")", "$1$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 11):

This code **removes all attributes** in style element except first attribute

```
string test = @" <div id=""first_line_info"" style=""width:490px; float:right;""> </div>";

var result = Regex.Replace(test,"(style=\")(.*?;).*\"", new MatchEvaluator((m)=>
    {
        return m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value + @"""";
    }));
```

This code **removes only float attribute** from style element:

```
var result2 = Regex.Replace(test, "(style=\".*?;).*(float:.*?;)\"", new MatchEvaluator((m) =>
    {
        return m.Groups[1].Value + @"""";
    }));
```

Answer (score 4):

We can achieve the same with DOM manipulation:

```
var dom = document.createElement('div');
dom.innerHTML = `
  <div id="first_line_info" style="width:490px; float:right;"> </div>
  <div id="first_line_info1" style="width:490px;float:left;float:right"> </div>
`;
var elem = dom.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = elem.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  elem[i].style.float = null;
  //float removed
}

console.log(dom.innerHTML);
```

From dom-manipulation plus regex replace method:
advantage: just need to match **float** not **style and float**

```
var dom = document.createElement('div');
dom.innerHTML = `
  <div id="first_line_info" style="width:490px; float:right;"> </div>
  <div id="first_line_info1" style="width:490px; float:right;float:left"> </div>
`;
var elem = dom.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = elem.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var style = elem[i].getAttribute('style');
  var regex = /(float:\w+;*)/g;

  style = style.replace(regex, "");
  //float removed

  elem[i].setAttribute('style', style);
}

console.log(dom.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the match group value, you could replace it.

```
(float:.*?;)

1.  float:right;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string data = "<div id=\"first_line_info\" style=\"width:490px; float:right;\"> </div>";
Regex floatPattern = new Regex(@"float\s*:\s*\w+\s*;?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
data = floatPattern.Replace(data, "");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.