# Javascript REGEX to find credit card number in string and mask

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to search a string and mask the a credit card for security.

```
"Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242"
"Hi here is my card number its visa 4242424242424242"
"Hi here is my card number its visa 4242-4242-4242-4242"
```

Should be converted to:

```
"Hi here is my card number its visa **** **** **** 4242"
```

I need to do this on the client in Javascript. I know there are quite a few resources and questions on the web and SO.

I have found two regex, but both throw errors: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

```
"Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242".match("(\d{4}-?){4}")
```

and

```
"Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242".match(\b4\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}[ -]\b)
```

I think the expressions are not compatible with JS?

I also understand they will return the string, I would then convert the string (mask it) and then use a simple replace on the original string.

Can anybody help me with the regex part of this problem?

Comment: You should have a look at the syntax of regular expressions in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: http://regex101.com

Comment: Can someone explain why the Questions is down-voted. It seems to be harder and harder to ask anything on SO, can someone please explain where the question fails to meet approval?

Comment: @MartinWebb I'm not sure either. The original issue you're having though is that `\d` is not valid. You need to escape ``\``. The second example would work other than you need to wrap your pattern in `/`. Also `[ -]\b` won't match anything in your case since `\b` matches positions between word characters and non-word characters (or start/end of line). I honestly think your question was downvoted for either 1. Not having used markdown (I edited your question to make it more legible) and/or 2. Because people *assume* everyone should know that you need to escape ``\`` or delimit a regex pattern

Comment: @MartinWebb I have no idea, but from experience you'll find more down votes on the questions about regex than most other questions on SO

Comment: @KyleFairns I'll agree with you on that one. Wanna see a neat one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791292/how-do-i-remove-a-style-element-from-an-inline-style-using-regex 68 downvotes.

Comment: @ctwheels Apologies for my lack of neatness. I will try and do better. Glad I asked appreciate the pointers.

Comment: @MartinWebb no worries, it's tough when starting, but eventually you learn how to please most (you can never please everyone). You should also take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). It has a lot of good information for SO (you can also get there by clicking on the `?` in the top right corner of the screen).

Comment: @ctwheels Starting I was programming in 1979. Now i feel really bad. New line of work?

Comment: No, right line of work. Now, however, people seem to be more concerned with presentation rather than semantics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/UMHmA7/1)

```
\b(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}(?=\d{4}\b)
```

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary. You can remove this if you want to catch cases such as `My visa is1234567812345678`
- `(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

  - `\d{4}` Match any digit 4 times
  - `[ -]?` Optionally match a space or hyphen
- `(?=\d{4}\b)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is 4 digits (and ensuring what follows it is not a word character). Similar to my first point, catching cards numbers that are followed by words such as `My visa is 1234567812345678please use it carefully`, use `(?=\d{4}(?!\d))` instead.

```js
const r = /\b(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}(?=\d{4}\b)/gm
const a = [
  "Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242",
  "Hi here is my card number its visa 4242424242424242",
  "Hi here is my card number its visa 4242-4242-4242-4242"
]
const subst = `**** **** **** `

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s.replace(r, subst))
})
```

Comment: I'm baffled why people just come on Questions and down-vote when the community is happy to solve a problem. Your answer was perfect - thank you.

Comment: @MartinWebb no worries! I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

the regexp can be passed as a string `".."` or regexp object `/../`. (when passed as string it is converted to RegExp object like with `new RegExp("..")`).

in first case the backslash must be doubled because of their special meaning between double quotes.

```
 "Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242".match("\\b(\\d{4}[- ]?){4}")
```

or

```
 "Hi here is my card number its visa 4242 4242 4242 4242".match(/\b(\d{4}[- ]?){4}/)
```

Comment: to downvoter my answer is about syntax that from question, OP didn't know